# Unit test workaround for HTML file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, backbone.js

I'm using jQuery and Backbone.js to map an `<input type="file">` to a Backbone model field, and I need to test that a filename change will propagate into the model.

Here's the line of test code that's causing problems:

```
target.$("input[name=fileName]").val(fileName).triggerHandler("change");
//                               ^ SecurityError thrown here
```

Here's the change event handler:

```
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "change input[name=fileName]": "onFileNameChanged"
    },

    onFileNameChanged: function () {
        this.model.set("ItemName", this.$("input[name=fileName]").val());
    }
});
```

I understand why I get a `SecurityError` with the test code, since after all the browser could very well think I'm trying to do a stealth upload in my JavaScript code. I'm not directly trying to get around that-- I just want to know how to unit test this test case.

Is there a good mocking technique or other workaround I can use for this case?